# Allowing, installing, and managing user defined node_modules at runtime

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, electron

I'm developing an Electron application that allows users to define snippets of JS code. This code will be compiled and executed for them. I want to include a feature similar to CodePen's external script feature, which allows users to search a CDN or paste a URL to a hosted script and then use that script in their pen, but with NPM packages.

How do I go about this? Is it possible to manage package dependencies at runtime?

Bonus: I serialize these user-defined functions for future use, and deserialize them at startup using `eval()`, if these functions have `require()`'s in them, will they be properly resolved?

Comment: Have you considered having a parent process that manages the user’s program? You can use child_process to execute and output the user’s program and then use it in the parent.

Comment: @Jack I have considered using a child_process to execute the function. But if the program requires a dependency that isn't installed globally won't it still fail? I need to ensure any dependency their program requires is available to the process running it

Comment: So you would have your program generate their program. Then you can install the user’s dependency locally and have their code require it.